# Add a redirect to a Tel link

Tags: html, redirect, hyperlink, tel

we're using a tel link (eg. `<a href="tel:+1-303-499-7111">+1 (303) 499-7111</a>`) so people can call us from their device. How can we also have the link redirect to another page with a tracking pixel so that we can measure the phone call as a conversion?

Comment: You could try and link it to a page, where you then assign that `tel:` URL to `location.href`. Or set up a click handler for the link, that triggers the tracking via JavaScript (most tracking service offer such an option.)

Comment: The click handler is the most obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you having the pixel as an img then you do tracking as follows:

```
<a href="tel:+1-303-499-7111" onclick=trackPixel()>+1 (303) 499-7111</a>
```

```
function trackPixel() {
  const pixelURL = `https://static.pixel.com/ase/25565/1553/aa.js`;
  new Image().src = pixelURL;
}
```

This will trigger the URL when the user clicks the phone number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do 2 redirect at a time you need to do some script code

```
<a onClick="makeCall()">+1234567890</a>
```

and the script is

```
function makeCall(){
  window.open('_link is here_', '_blank'); 
  window.open('tel:+1303499-7111', '_parent'); 
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It actually works fine with you use tel:// All you have to do is create a call now link that goes to your script to track the call and then redirect to the tel:// link

Here are the sample headers from my test session.

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 20:24:08 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: tel://5551212
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.40
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
```